# What is the "usual way" to create a GUI for your application?

Tags: java, user-interface

Hey guys I'm new to programing and I'm just gettin into UI design.

There are some things I've gotten so far, like I should only use a JFrame per application and other guidelines like that. What I don't understand is... what is the proper way to join your business logic with the GUI?

What I mean is, let's pretend I've just created an application that runs on console (or whatever), and I want to create a GUI for it, so, I've seen on the net that people create a JForm-derived class as a main class and that's it. But is this the proper way? I would like to keep my original "Main class" (the class that uses every other class I've created for my project) and define the form as a field of it, something like that.

Is it possible? If so, how can I achieve this? I have all my logic on that main class I just talked you about, so when I instantiate the form inside of it, I don't know how to make the form use and alter the fields and use the methods I defined in the main class (Sorry if I'm not making myself clear).

How you do, experienced people, do it? What is the "good practice" way? Thanks for taking your time and sorry if it's a  noob question.

Comment: You should take a look at the MVC pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: And may be at JavaFX 2.

Comment: @Paranaix Thanks for suggesting that, seems interesting. I stumbled upon this video about the MVC model: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTVVa2gfht8#t=658 , and I kinda get it, but what if my "model" is made from several classes? Should I instantiate every model class in my controller? Or there's a way to "unify the model into only one entity"? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Andrey I wanted to get into JavaFX because it looks cooler :D But when I tried it I found some concepts I'm not familiar with right now (Or maybe I understood it wrong), but I'm planning to learn it in a future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no professional but I can't stand working with JFrames and Graphics objects.
Most of the time I use the lwjgl library. I know this library is for games but It is
great for UI's as well. The reason it is so easy is because you simply give buttons their
X and Y coordinates without having to worry about layouts. You can make your own images and
import them easily, so if you want your button to look like an image you created no problem.
Because it is made for games it is also very fast and fluid.

This may not be the best way but it works for me so I thought I would share anyway.

Hope it helps.

Here is the lwjgl website: http://www.lwjgl.org/

Here is a video series that helped get me started: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v56I5UWrYY&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PL19F2453814E0E315

Answer (score 0):

Paranaix already mentioned in his comment about the [model - view - controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture.

I mostly construct Java Swing GUI applications.

I build the model first.  This could be considered a "first cut", since I update the model as I construct the view.

Next I build the view.  I construct all of my Swing components by hand.  I find that GUI builders harm more than they help.  Building the view usually causes me to modify the model.

Finally I construct the controller.

Here's a more detailed description of how I put together a [dice game](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=460) from my blog.